# Why does my code output "Incorrect" though the answer is correct?

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, counter

I was just wanting some help with some of my code.
I have it set up as such:

```
public partial class frmAdditionTutor : Form
{
    public int I = 0;
    public frmAdditionTutor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int NumberOne = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        int NumberTwo = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        lblEquation.Text = NumberOne.ToString() + " + " + NumberTwo.ToString() + "= ?";
    }

    private void btnSolve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int NumberOne = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        int NumberTwo = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        int TotalAmount = NumberOne + NumberTwo;
        int UserInputs = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);

        if ((NumberOne + NumberTwo) == UserInputs)
        {
            lblRightorWrong.Text = "Correct!";
            I++;
            txtAmountCorrect.Text = I.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblRightorWrong.Text = "Incorrect!";
            I++;
            txtQuestionCount.Text = I.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens when I launched the program is that it gives the user an equation to solve.
When they enter their problem, the code checks if it is correct or incorrect. If the answer is correct, I want it to display **Correct!** in the `Label` and then add `+1` to my `AmountCorrect` `TextBox`.

The issue is that no matter if the user enters it correctly, the code thinks that it is incorrect and does not add on to the counter.

I want my code to randomly display different variables to add to when the person gets the answer correct.

Comment: You're recreating NumberOne and Two when you click solve which will be different to what is shown in `lblEquation.Text`.

Comment: Just like stated by Loocid, within the btnSolve_Click method you are getting 2 new random numbers (NumberOne and NumberTwo respectively). What you might want to do is create instance variable Total, set the Total in frmAdditionTutor and then use that instance variable to compare it to UserInputs.

Comment: So I would change it to  var Total = NumberOne + NumberTwo;

            if (Total == UserInputs) and try to run? I want a user to get another random number to solve when they solve the equation correctly, hence the randomization of numbers.

Comment: You would declare Total just like I variable -> public int Total = 0;. Then, in frmAdditionTutor you would set Total = NumberOne + NumberTwo, and then in btnSolve_Click you would have if (Total == UserInputs)... If you want to ask user to solve another equation (when they answer correctly), you would need a flag and a loop that will keep on looping until the user answers incorrectly.

Comment: @SrdanRistic Tried that method, no dice. Same results.

Comment: Have you debugged, in order to see which values are being compared at
if (Total == UserInputs)

Comment: @SrdanRistic After running debug, I think when the user presses "solve," NumberOne and NumberTwo change their random integer values THEN checks if the answer is correct or not. So I need the code to check the total value (and state if it is correct or not) before switching over to new random numbers from what I have debugged.

Comment: Those variables also need to be at an instance level

Answer (score 2):

In the code you were creating new NumberOne and NumberTwo while clicking the solve button.
If you want to create the random question again do it after the calculation. You can also use a method to make the code reusable.

```
 public partial class frmAdditionTutor : Form
    {
        public int CorrectAnswerCount = 0;
        public int IncorrectAnswerCount = 0;
        int NumberOne = 0;
        int NumberTwo = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateRandomQuestion();
        }

        private void btnSolve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int TotalAmount = NumberOne + NumberTwo;
            int UserInputs = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);

            if (TotalAmount == UserInputs)
            {
                lblRightorWrong.Text = "Correct!";
                CorrectAnswerCount++;
                txtAmountCorrect.Text = CorrectAnswerCount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblRightorWrong.Text = "Incorrect!";
                IncorrectAnswerCount++;
                txtAmountWrong.Text = IncorrectAnswerCount.ToString();
            }

            CreateRandomQuestion();
        }

        public void CreateRandomQuestion()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            NumberOne = rand.Next(500) + 100;
            NumberTwo = rand.Next(500) + 100;
            lblEquation.Text = NumberOne.ToString() + " + " + NumberTwo.ToString() + "= ?";
            txtInput.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is Ok. You could add something like: `if (txtInput.TextLength < 1) return;` in the `Button.Click()` handler to avoid a `FormatException` and/or use `int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()` to filter invalid integer values.

Comment: @Akhitha Thank you! I will be looking at making changes. Any tips on how to TryParse?

Comment: @Blake Bratu  Yes, it does. You made a mistake in pasting the code. Also, *The code does not work* doesn't mean anything. You have to specify what error you get and where the debugger stops in the code you're using. Possibly, update your question with the code you're actually using, so the error can be seen and corrected.

Comment: @BlakeBratu Can you specify what error you got with this code?